# How to display unicode / hexadecimal emoji and octal literals in HTML using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, unicode, vue.js, emoji

So I'm getting such response from webserver:

`"\ud83d\ude48\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude30\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\udc4f\ud83c\udffd\ud83d\udc4c\ud83c\udffd\ud83d\udd1d\u2714\ufe0f\ud83d\ude42 \344\366\374\337\u015b\u0161"`

which after decoding should look like this:

✔️ äöüßśš

äöüß are encoded as octal literals `\344\366\374\337`

To display correctly this message (not encoded plain text) I've used:

`{{ JSON.parse('"' + messageContent.message  + '"') }}`

And it worked perfectly for escaped unicode values but when octal literals appear it's not, so here is the problem - ES6 won't allow for using octal literals since they are deprecated, and an error occurs, so what I've done is just finding with regex for octal literals and then parse them using: `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(parseInt(val.replace('\\', ''), 8), 10))` so that from eg: `\344` I'm getting ä. After I replace octals, I have to search for any unicode characters and again, parse it one by one using `` JSON.parse(`"${val}"`) `` (here is the same case as described below - if I hardcode a string and return just `\ud83d\ude48` I don't have to parse it with JSON.parse, it just returns ). I believe it's not optimal solution.

The other strange thing for me is when I try display message directly from server response (even if it does not contain any octal literals) using
`{{ response.message }}` it will print as normal string, but when I create new variable and assign exact the same value as I receive from server:

`message='\ud83d\ude48\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude30\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\udc4f\ud83c\udffd\ud83d\udc4c\ud83c\udffd\ud83d\udd1d\u2714\ufe0f\ud83d\ude42'`
and then display it

`{{ message }}` displayed value is ✔️.

And last thing: even when I use my algorithm i'm just looking for text that match `/\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}/g` sometimes it does not parse unicode well - eg: if user change a skin color, the unicode message would be: `\ud83d\udc4d\ud83c\udffd`, decoded: , but with this regex it would be `�\udffd`

It's possible to make some small changes on the backend side if it's necessary, but it's used also by mobile apps that are finished so that changes should not affect them.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try manually decoding the unicode escape sequences (`\uXXXX`) and octal escape sequences (`\XXX`) as follows:

```js
const response = '\\ud83d\\ude48\\ud83d\\ude02\\ud83d\\ude30\\ud83d\\ude09\\ud83d\\udc4f\\ud83c\\udffd\\ud83d\\udc4c\\ud83c\\udffd\\ud83d\\udd1d\\u2714\\ufe0f\\ud83d\\ude42 \\344\\366\\374\\337\\u015b\\u0161'
const decoded = response
  .replace(/\\u(....)/g, (match, p1) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16)))
  .replace(/\\(\d{3})/g, (match, p1) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1,  8)))
console.log(decoded)
```

The server is sending you a string containing the literal characters `\ud83d\ude48` (and so on), so the string must be explicitly decoded somehow by converting the escape sequences into the unicode characters they represent. On the other hand, if a *string literal* in JavaScript code contains the characters `\ud83d\ude48` then it will be automatically decoded into .

Observe the difference between these two strings:

```js
console.log('\ud83d\ude48')
console.log('\\ud83d\\ude48')
```